# How to see TLS version with incoming API request in Azure portal?

Tags: azure, tls1.2, azure-log-analytics, azureportal, azure-webapps

In the Microsoft Azure portal, is there a way to see request URLs along with the TLS version negotiated?

**Background**

I have a web app that includes an API that used by several third parties. I would like to set the minimum TLS version to TLS 1.2 in my web app settings.

Before I update the minimum TLS version, I want to see what requests are being made using old TLS versions.

I know with my storage account I also have, I can include logs in the log analytics to detect TLS versions, so I was hoping there was something similar I could use for my web app.

So far, all I can find for my web app is the Minimum TLS Version Checker under Diagnose & Solve Problems. This isn't very helpful since it only gives me the number of requests with no further detail. Surely the detail has to be available somewhere? I am not an expert in the Azure portal, so I am hoping there is an easy way to find the request URL + TLS version.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can check TLS version with the incoming requests either in `Application Insights` or by using `Diagnostic Setting`.

***Using Application Insights:***

- I have configured Application Insights in my API Web App and deployed the app to Azure App service.

[image]

- Enable Application Insights for the deployed App service.

[image]

- We can send custom logs to Application Insights by retrieving the TLS version and URL of the app.
- Logs can be seen in transaction search.

[image]

> I know with my storage account I also have, I can include logs in the log analytics to detect TLS versions

Another option is from `Diagnostic Setting`.

- Using Diagnostic Setting we can send the logs to Storage Account or Log Analytics Workspace for the Azure App Service.

[image]

- As you have already mentioned that you know how to check logs in `Log Analytics Workspace`, same way you can send the WebApp logs to the selected workspace.

[image]

***Update:***

The TLS Version which is set in the Configuration section can be seen in
`KUDU Console` => `Environment` => `HTTP headers` and `Server variables`

[image]

[image]

- Use the below code to retrieve the value in the controller.

```cs
string ?tlsVersion= HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-TlsVersion"];
_logger.LogInformation($"TLS : {tlsVersion}" );
```

Comment: I have Application Insights enabled but I am not seeing TLS version in the Transaction Search. Is there something special I have to configure for TLS version to show? Also, I have tried the Diagnostic Setting but I can't seem to find TLS version there either. I have tried the HTTP logs category, but I'm not seeing TLS version being reported in the logs.

Comment: Send the custom log by retrieving the tlsversion in code.

Comment: @IMSsam - Please check the update section in the sol.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to retrieve the TLS version from the header X-Forwarded-TlsVersion just as you suggested!